# How to add "\" in a path varible?

Tags: python, string, path

I'm trying to insert backslash , which is going to be used as a path variable but when I do this:

```
i='02222022130300393.png'
path=r'C:\Users\kavin.r\Desktop\test\Level_Typical_Images\'+i
```

I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

When I tried like this:

```
i='02222022130300393.png'
path=r'C:\Users\kavin.r\Desktop\test\Level_Typical_Images\\'+i
```

I got

```
FileNotFoundError:No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\kavin.r\\Desktop\\test\\Level_Typical_Images\\\\02222022130300393.png'
```

Comment: For this specific case, the simplest approach is to use string formatting - since that would be the preferred way to put the strings together *anyway*, and it happens to avoid trying to use a single backslash at the end of the string. That said, you do not need backslashes here at all in the first place.

Comment: As an aside: the `[r]` tag is for a programming language named R, not for Python's raw strings.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it works for Python too

Comment: You should use `path = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\kavin.r\Desktop\test\Level_Typical_Images', i)` to join the path components and avoid the issue completely. Another possibility is to use `path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/kavin.r/Desktop/test/Level_Typical_Images') / i`.